# JMS Serializer event is not working

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am sure it is a small error but I cannot find it.
I am trying to follow [the official doc](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system) and implement an event listener on the pre_serialize event.

My service declaration:

```
 <service id="app.question_serializer_subscriber" class="AppBundle\Serializer\QuestionSerializerSubscriber">
     <tag name="jms_serializer.event_subscriber"/>
 </service>
```

My subscriber:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;

class QuestionSerializerSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'event'  => 'serializer.pre_serialize',
                'method' => 'onPreSerialize',
            )
        );
    }

    public function onPreSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        die('in event');
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
        $question   = $repo->findLastVersionByQuestionId((int) $questionId);
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

        $context = new SerializationContext();
        return new JsonResponse(json_decode(
            $serializer->serialize(
                $question,
                'json',
                $context
            ),
            true
        ));
```

When I access the route my entity Question is serialized and displayed, but why does the `die('in event');` is not displayed ?

Maybe it has a relation with the fact that my object is a Doctrine entity ([issue 666](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/666) or [PR 677](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/677) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally find the issue. The problem is

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
```

This does not work but this does:

```
$serializer =  $this->get('jms_serializer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class attribute, as example:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'event'  => 'serializer.pre_serialize',
            'class'  => 'FQCN_class_name',
            'method' => 'onPreSerialize',
        )
    );
}
```

Another difference regarding the doc is in the argument of the class method: you should use `PreSerializeEvent` instead of `ObjectEvent`:

So like this:

```
public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
{
    // ...
}
```

Check your service is correctly load from the container as example with the console command:

> `php app/console debug:container --tag=jms_serializer.event_subscriber`

Hope this help

Comment: I already tried, and I tried with  'format' => 'json' too, but it does not work :(

Comment: you can should try with the `onPostSerialize` method to see if this works

Comment: I have the four events linked to the same function (the one with the die) and my json is still displayed

Comment: see if your service is listed in the tagged service of the container, as example launching this command: `php app/console debug:container --tag=jms_serializer.event_subscriber`

Comment: Yes it is listed !

Comment: Already tried and does not work either. Maybe it has to do with my Object being a Doctrine entity (see my edited question)

Comment: If your service is not listed when launching `php app/console debug:container --tag=jms_serializer.event_subscriber` check if your service is tagged with `public: true`.